# How to convert \u00253A and \u00252F in string using php?

Tags: php

How to convert \u00253A and \u00252F in string using php ?

I treid to use this code but not work.

```
<?php
$match ="http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.google.com"
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/', function ($match) {
    return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');
}, $str);
echo $str;
?>
```

How can i do ?

Comment: Convert to what exactly?

Comment: convert to `http://www.google.com` sir

Comment: Alright, this is a mightily messed up string then. It's a JSON-encoded (?) URL-encoding. How did it get that way in the first place? Fix this at the source, this is not something you normally want to be dealing with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That string has been URL-encoded, turning `:` into `%3A`, which has then been JSON-encoded (presumably?) to turn `%` into `\u0025`. This is mightily messed up and should be fixed at the source, this is not something you want to generally deal with as normal.

Here's how to decode it back:

```
$match = "http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.google.com";
echo rawurldecode(json_decode('"' . $match . '"'));
```